# Linear Algebra Simple Proof

Tags: proof-writing

Prove the following result, or provide a counterexample to disprove it.

```
 There is a vector space which contains exactly 2 vectors within it.
```

For this question, I'm not sure where to start. To me this statement seems to be true, since I only have to provide one example of said vector space in order to prove this statement.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\mathbb{Z}_2$ as a vector space over itself.